# Can cross correlation be used to see if filtering of a signal has changed it too much?

Tags: vibration, signal-processing, signal

I am filtering a signal, and want to check if I am not over filtering it , I wanted to use cross correlation , but I am not sure if it is a good technique. usually I get something like the following as Cross Correlation between the signal itself and the filtered one. i sit a good criteria?:

The filter is 4th order Bessel, lowpass filter, with 250Hz pass band for a 512Hz signal. no time lag between filtered and original

[image]

Comment: Could you please put a plot with the original and the filtered data?

Comment: well, I have limit of permission. I can't. is it possible to answer based on this ?

Comment: The filter is 4th order Bessel, lowpass filter, with 250Hz pass band for a 512Hz signal. no time lag between filtered and original

Comment: I've never really used cross correlation for that purpose. Maybe you are on to something but I can't really tell. My advice, is have a look at your original and filtered signal, try to some some overfitting and check whether you can make sense using the cross correlation.